# How use Azure Artifacts Credential Provider for Nuget feeds, with VisualStudio 2022, Linux Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, visual-studio, nuget, containers

I'm running C# unit tests in Visual Studio 2022, for native Linux system calls, in Linux .NET 6.0 SDK containers. In the first attempts, I had a PAT (Personal Access Token) in plain text in the Dockerfile, which I want to replace by *ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN*, taken from environment variable.

There is basically just the *.csproj* and the *Dockerfile*, no *docker-compose.yml*. Optional *launchSettings.json* in the project.

I don't get any value for *FEED_ACCESSTOKEN*, trying either variable *$(FEED_ACCESSTOKEN)* or *$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)*, test with *RUN echo*. Visual Studio shows both with blue underlines, "*Property '...' is not defined*".

How can I get an access token? I found a *NuGetAuthenticate* task under Azure DevOps, *docker-compose.yml* examples. I'm not even sure whether I shall use it as docker build or  run parameter (therefore I left both in the example).

**The project file:**

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>

      <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <AssemblyName>xxx.UnitTests</AssemblyName>

    <RootNamespace>xxx.UnitTests</RootNamespace>

      <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
      <DockerfileContext>../..</DockerfileContext>
      <DockerfileRunArguments>-e FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)</DockerfileRunArguments>
      <DockerfileBuildArguments>--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)</DockerfileBuildArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>

<!-- ... -->

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.17.0" />

<!-- ... -->

</Project>
```

**The Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
RUN echo "Feed access token: $FEED_ACCESSTOKEN"
VOLUME "C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp" "/tmp/hostuser"
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR src
COPY ["src/xxx.UnitTests/xxx.UnitTests.csproj", "src/xxx.UnitTests/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
# [add credentials to feed endpoints, redacted]

RUN dotnet restore "src/xxx.UnitTests/xxx.UnitTests.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/xxx.UnitTests"
RUN dotnet build "xxx.UnitTests.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "xxx.UnitTests.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "xxx.UnitTests.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN assigned in the project file, so asuming you have it created as a environment variable? I would remove the `=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)` from your `--build-arg`, and then set a user defined environment variable named `FEED_ACCESSTOKEN`. If you pass just `--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN` to docker build, it will prorogate the existing user environment variable value as the argument. Be sure to start visual studio AFTER creating the environment variable, else it will not be known to the already running application.

You can also use this method for publish profile (pubxml) files. As they they tend to not get included in source control commits, you can just type in the PAT in the file. Then use the project's publish menu option in visual studio.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Custom</WebPublishMethod>
    <DockerPublish>true</DockerPublish>
    <RegistryUrl>https://my.container.registry/</RegistryUrl>
    <UserName>admin</UserName>
    <PublishImageTag>latest</PublishImageTag>
    <PublishProvider>ContainerRegistry</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <ProjectGuid>....</ProjectGuid>
    <PersonalAccessToken>my-personal-access-token</PersonalAccessToken>
    <DockerfileBuildArguments>--build-arg nuget_pat=$(PersonalAccessToken)</DockerfileBuildArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```